# Create an NSView in an event and return it through a parameter

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

I'd like to create an NSView derivative in an event and return it to the calling procedure. something like

```
    ...
if assigned(FMyEvent) then
   FMyEvent(newview)
..
```

and the event would be assigned something like

```
procedure TForm6.AssignView(var view: Pointer);
begin
  view := Pointer(TNSButton.Wrap(TNSButton.Wrap(TNSButton.OCClass.alloc).initWithFrame(MakeNSRect(200,0,100,50))));
end;
```

which will return an NSButton in this case.

Now because I want the event to be published I can't use an NSView as a parameter - because NSView is an OSX only definition and the form designer needs to know about the event in Windows as well. So I made it a Pointer type - but this crashes, it looks like a reference counter problem looking at the stack trace.

Could anyone suggest an alternative? or maybe I have to do something to increment the reference count? or if any one can point to some documentation on the delphi/osx interface that would be great.

**Update:**

I Cheated and just made a container - like this

```
  TNSViewContainer = class
  {$IFDEF MACOS}
  private
    FView: NSView;
    procedure SetView(const Value: NSView);
  published
    property View : NSView read FView write SetView;
  {$ENDIF}
  end;
```

and I just pass one of these around - works a treat.

Comment: Since you're using `NSView` & `NSButton`, I guess your tag [tag:ios] can be removed, right?

Comment: I put IOS in because the same thing would apply to a UIView - and there's probably more IOS developers using Delphi than OSX

Comment: As an iOS developer, I prefer using native Objective-C.

Comment: Have you had a look at Delphi - I prefer it over Objective C, and you can use your code on Windows/Android and OSX. It's worth a look

Comment: Will look into Delphi if have time. p.s. currently using C# for cross-platform App via Unity 3D. Been using JavaScript & Lua for other cross-platform Apps, found that one size doesn't fit all. Lots of problems found.